# Value[] attribute in my decision tree is not consistent with number of samples

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees, gini-index

I read that value[] attribute in a decision tree shows the distribution of the samples across class 1 and class 2.

However, my value[] is not adding up. In the root node for example, there are 14 samples and the value=[10.0,10.0]. Some nodes have a floating point value.

[image]